# Longtable landscape: toprules exceed margin and caption is centered

Tags: captions, margins, longtable, landscape

My longtable in landscape mode has formatting problems: the rules (top/mid/bottom) exceed the margin and the caption is centred (but I want it to be left-aligned).

I haven't shortened the content of the table, sorry in advance, but since I need it as it is (with itemize etc.) - I thought it would be best to leave it as it is.

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
toc=bibliography,
numbers=noendperiod
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
left=3cm,
right=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.0cm,
includehead,
includefoot
]{geometry}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\scriptsize}
\usepackage[font={normal}]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries\rmfamily}


\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{0.72\linewidth}
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{parskip}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[4cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \tocfill}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\raggedbottom
\singlespacing\label{key}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \footnotesize
    {\def\arraystretch{2}\tabcolsep=10pt
        \begin{longtable}
            {
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
            }
            \caption[Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes]{Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes \cite{Mulder.1996}}
            \label{tab:pressuredriven}\\
            \toprule
            &Microfiltraton&Ultrafiltration&Nanofiltration&Reverse Osmosis\\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            \caption[Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes]{Characteristics of pressure driven membrane processes (continued)}\\
            \toprule    
            &   Microfiltraton                              &   Ultrafiltration                 &   Nanofiltration                              &   Reverse Osmosis                     \\
            \midrule
            \endhead
            Separation principle                &   sieving                                     &   sieving                         &   solution-diffusion                          &   solution-diffusion                  \\  
            Separation size                     &   particles                                   &   \rr macromolecules, colloids    &   low molecular weight solutes                &   micro solutes, monovalent ions      \\
            Osmotic pressure                    &   negligible                                  &   negligible                      &   1-25 bar            &           15 - 80 bar                         \\ 
            Applied pressure            &   0.1 - 2 bar                                 &   1 - 10 bar                      &   5 - 20 bar                                  &   10 - 100 bar                        \\
            Structure                           &   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} symmetric,\newline asymmetric \end{minipage}                &   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} asymmetric,\newline dense top layer \end{minipage}      & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \raggedright  asymmetric/composite, \newline dense structure  \end{minipage}  & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}   asymmetric,\newline thin dense top layer    \end{minipage} \\
            Separating layer thickness          & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}   symmetric 10-150 um, \newline asymmetric 1 um   \end{minipage}  &   0.1 - 1.0 \textmu m             &   0.1 - 1 \textmu m       & <1 \textmu m          \\
            Pore size                           &   10 - 0.05 \textmu m                         &   0.05 \textmu m - 1.0 nm         &   < 2.0 nm                                    &       < 2.0 nm                            \\
            Flux in $l/(m^2\cdot h \cdot bar)$  &   > 50                                        &   10 - 50                         &   1.4 - 12                                    &   0.05 - 1.4                          \\
                                            \\
            Membrane material                           &       
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
                    \item hydrophobic polymeric (PTFE, PVDF, PP, PE)
                    \item hydrophilic polymeric (cellulose, PC, PSU/PES, PI/PEI, PA, PEEK)
                    \item ceramic (Al2O3, ZrO2, TiO2, SiC) 
                    \item glass (SiO2), carbon, metals (stainless steel, palladium, tungsten, silver)
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
                    \item polymeric (PSU/PES, PVDF, PAN, cellulose, PE/PEI, PA, PEEK) 
                    \item ceramic (Al2O3, ZrO2)
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\centering
                    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
                        \item integral-asymmetric: \newline
                        cellulose esters (CDA, CTA), \newline
                        aromatic PA, \newline
                        PBI, PAH, PI
                        \item composites
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}
            }
            \\
            Characterisation                    & 
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item SEM
                    \item bubble-point method
                    \item mercury porometry
                    \item permeation
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item cuff-off method
                    \item thermoporometry
                    \item liquid displacement
                    \item permporometry
                    \item gas ad-/desorption
                    \item permeation
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            & 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                        \item permeation methods (gas/liquids)
                        \item DSC/DTA methods
                        \item density measurements
                        \item WAXS
                        \item plasma etching
                        \item surface analysis
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}
            }   \\
            Industrial application  
            &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright 
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item analytical applications
                    \item sterilisation and clarification (food, beverages, pharmaceuticals)
                    \item ultrapure water for semiconductors
                    \item cell harvesting, bioreactor in biotechnology
                    \item medical application (plasmapheresis)
                    \item water treatment
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            & 
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item dairy
                    \item food (starch, proteins)
                    \item metallurgy (oil-water emulsions)
                    \item textile applications
                    \item pharmaceutical (enzymes, antibiotics)
                    \item water treatment
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item desalination of brackish water
                    \item micropollutents removal
                    \item water softening
                    \item waste water treatment
                    \item retention of dyes
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                    \item desalination of brackish and sea water
                    \item ultrapure water production
                    \item food juice and sugars concentration
                    \item milk concentration
                \end{itemize}
            \end{minipage}
            \\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{5}{p{\dimexpr0.93\linewidth+4\tabcolsep}}{\scriptsize footnote}\\
        \end{longtable}
    }
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: longtable are always (really) full width, it modifies hline to just span the visible columns (internally like cline) but bookmark rules do what they do. Simplest would be to use `\hline` or use bookmark `\cmidrule` rules, specifying the columns to span.

Comment: `booktabs` claims to now be compatible with `longtable`, so you might start by checking you have an up-to-date version.

Comment: my version is up to date

Comment: @DavidCarlisle both options don´t change anything with the line to exceed the margin

Comment: If I minimise the example and `\let` the `booktabs` macros to `\hline`, the rules do behave, but the `longtable` is still too wide because the contents of the columns end up too wide. Maybe that's an underlying issue here?

Comment: the problem is verfull \hbox (389.43307pt too wide) in alignment at lines 90--207  (I reduced tabcolsep) but still 5*4cm + 10 * tabcolsep ought to fit, I'll look later

Comment: oh it's the minipage (you should remove them all) but specifically this one `\multicolumn{2}{c}{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\centering` `\linewidth` here is the linewidth for the landscape page so it can not fit in the table.

Comment: Oh thanks - but I when remove the minipage I don´t get well aligned itemize environments. Is there another option for this?